# Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, hibernate-session

I understand this question has been asked many time, but most can't explain my problem:

```
@RequestMapping("/testing")
public String testing(HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model) 
{
    Transaction ut = session.openSession().beginTransaction();

    session.getCurrentSession(); // error here

    ut.commit();

    return "testing";
}
```

Why I am getting the error

```
Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread.
```

If I annotate the method with `@Transactional`, it is working perfectly fine. Because I have `@EnableTransactionManagement` in my spring context.

I want to try something to understand the difference between `getCurrentSession`and `openSession`, so I created test case above.

`getCurrentSession` is called within a active Transaction context, why it is still throwing me error???

Refer the code from [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after so long time of research, I found out I have miss out the [paragraph](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) below:

> You will not see these code snippets in a regular application; fatal
>   (system) exceptions should always be caught at the "top". In other
>   words, the code that executes Hibernate calls in the persistence
>   layer, and the code that handles RuntimeException (and usually can
>   only clean up and exit), are in different layers. The current context
>   management by Hibernate can significantly simplify this design by
>   accessing a SessionFactory. Exception handling is discussed later in
>   this chapter.

So the example showing there indeed will not be working in regular scenario...

I have to do as below:

```
// BMT idiom with getCurrentSession()
try {
    UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext()
                            .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");

    tx.begin();

    // Do some work on Session bound to transaction
    factory.getCurrentSession().load(...);
    factory.getCurrentSession().persist(...);

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    tx.rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

Which mean, the usage of `getCurrentSession` is pretty restricted, it must be running in a `active` (and specific) transaction.